# when triggering click event of my link, the event is triggered as well on the parent .post_box, causing the loop

Tags: jquery

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.post_box').on('click', function(e) { 
        jQuery(this).find(".read_more").trigger("click");
    });  
});
```

When I click on the div post_box it trigger a link (pop up greybox)located in sub div of post_box which has the class read_more, right now it work good but the problem when I close the link greybox, and click again on the div post_box it doesn't work, I have to refresh the page to click it.

If I put the on() function instead , on the first click it will trigger the link and get blocked, I think it trigger the link more than one because of the sub divs this is the HTML code

```
<div class="post_box" >
    <div class="post_box_top">
        <div class="post_box_center">
            <div class="post_box_content">

                <div class="post_date">

                </div>
                <div class="post_content">

              <?php   echo   $content_post = get_post(get_the_ID());?>

                </div>
                <div class="post_footer">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read_more"  rel="gb_pageset[search_sites]"  data-greybox-type="iframe">Read more</a>
               // this the link i should trigger when someone click on the <div class="post_box">   
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

http://ec2-107-22-235-75.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ take a look here please, this the site with function one() in case I change to on() when you click on div it block http://haiders.imcserver.ro/telugu you can take a look at the second case with on() here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of triggering a click event I would create an even handler (function) and just run the function, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var     
    readMoreHandler = function (ev) {
        el = $(this).find(".read_more")
        // open read more for the above element
    };


    $('.post_box').on('click', readMoreHandler);  
});
```

This way you don't have event bubbling problem

Comment: This is .read_more click that bubbles, not the .post_box one, i think as .post-box is the parent

Comment: You need to add this to the event handler of `$('.read_more')`, not `$('.post_box')`.

Comment: thank you all but sorry what is the final solution if somebody know

Comment: This won't work. The `stopPropagation` handler needs to be on the links, not the container.

Comment: @Asad where did I say that it should be on the container?

Comment: @tborychowski Oh, I misunderstood the first part. You should specify the handler it needs to be put on. (I'll undo my DV once you edit, it's locked in unfortunately)

Comment: @Asad and you should stop down-voting without reading and making sure that the solution actually works :-)

Comment: @tborychowski I downvoted because you just said you should add this in "the event handler". The only event handler in the question is the one attached to the container (not the links), and adding `stopPropagation` in it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping propagation on the links:

```
$(".read_more").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post_box').on('click', function(e) { 
        $(this).find(".read_more").click();
    }); 
});
```

That way the event handler for the outer div isn't triggered when the event bubbles from the links.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/7wFQz/